# Reproject vector layer error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I have a  vector layer in `GCS_WGS_84`. The data it possess is world soil data obtained from [this link](http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/resources.get?id=14116&fname=DSMW.zip&access=private). I am working in `UTM zone 45N`. Hence I need to reproject the CRS to `WGS_84_UTM45N`.

I imported this downloaded data into qgis, right clicked on the layer, and clikced on save as. I saved it with a new name and selected the CRS while saving as `WGS_84_UTM45N`.
But it returned the following error::

```
Export to vector file failed.
Error: Failed to transform a point while drawing a feature with ID '0'. Writing stopped. (Exception: forward transform of
(-0.605210, 1.459058)
PROJ.4: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +to +proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits)
```

Comment: Data in UTM zone 45 should be in the range of longitude 84E-90E. Input data from zone 30 (6W-0E) is *completely* out of range. Either your input isn't what you think it is or some other horrific thing has occurred to your data.

Comment: The reported values could be in radians. If I convert them to degrees, I get 15, 83 (approx.). Try swapping the input coordinates or use the +order=2,1 in the +proj command.

Comment: @Vince the data I need indeed lies in long 84E to 90E. I need to reproject this wgs84 to wgs84utm45N for me to work properly. But it simply wouldn't let me reproject. Here's the link to the data : http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/resources.get?id=14116&fname=DSMW.zip&access=private

Comment: @mkennedy I'm sorry but I am not familiar with what you have suggested. I am a newbie in GIS applications.

Comment: Please do not fill the the comments with personal communication. Your job here is to curate a Question. Any clarifications need to be made within the question body. Either the data is in the correct range or it isn't.  This is something that only you can determine (mostly because you didn't provide a useful link to your source or report the extent). Please [Edit] the question to add two paragraphs explaining what exact data you obtained and its data extent, and what processing steps you performed before the error occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you choose the CRS exactly? The CRS "World Geodetic System 1984 UTM fuseau 45" does not have the same proj4 string in QGis, did you use a custom CRS?

Anyway, the error message is quite clear: the point you try to convert, (-0.605210, 1.459058) in WGS84, is outside the boundaries of the CRS. This coordinate system is not adapted to points around (0,0) in WGS84, you should use a different projection for that. You can see here roughly the area where it can be useful: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-45n/

Comment: I'm sorry but I don' understand what you are trying to say. Do you mean why and how did I choose WGS 84 UTM 45N ? 
 I've been working in a project and all other layers (vectors, rasters) are in wgs84, utm45N. Now this soil database that I downloaded from FAO is in GCS WGS 84 (as written in its metadata). When I import this soil data into my project with crs set to wgs 84 everything aligns(OTF projection is ON). But when I try to reproject, this error occurs.

Comment: Also I'm new to GIS and I don't have in depth knowledge in CRS and its applications. I can just find my way by changing crs and reprojecting into another CRS, but this time it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a link to the FAO data? Where are they supposed to be? If the data is actually in WGS84, the point causing issue is in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean, near the gulf of Guinea. Is it correct? If you have data all around the world in this layer, converting to UTM45N will not work, maybe you should clip your data to the extent you are interested in first. Or maybe the source data is not actually in WGS84 and QGis already applied a transformation.

Comment: yes, the data is in wgs84 and the data for whole world is provided in there. Here's the download link.. it should download DSMW.zip file: 
http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/resources.get?id=14116&fname=DSMW.zip&access=private